# user pam.d configuration files to prevent updates overwriting them

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, pam

My server is running and I have modified `/etc/pam.d/common-password`. When certain programs are installed or there are system updates, it needs to update that file so it asks me if I want to the file should be overwritten or not.

> One or more of the files /etc/pam.d/common-{auth,account,password,session} have been locally modified.  Please indicate whether these local changes should be overridden using the system-provided configuration. If you decline this option, you will need to manage your system's authentication configuration by hand.
>
> Override local changes to /etc/pam.d/common-*?

Is it possible to put my changes in another file that pam will still use so that I don't have to deal with this message in the future?

If it helps, I am changing the line:

```
password    requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
```

To this:

```
password      requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10 difok=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 gecoschec
```

Comment: You can put your changes in a file and get them included by ``@include``. But each time the system updates you'll end up with a new version of the file that you have to edit and the ``@include``